# custom textfield with two different color (inner and outer)

Tags: css

Im a beginner in css so please bear with me :D

I tried to create this  custom textfield :

[image]

So i have 2 different colors, just say color A for the inner background (the big one) and color B for the outer one.

So i think the outer one (color B) could be a `<span>` and color A is a `<input type="text">`
(I dont know if this is the best way to do it, im very open to other solution because my lack of experience in css)

So this is my html code :

```
<div id="search">
        <span><input type="text"  id="txtSearch"/></span>
</div>
```

And this is my css :

```
/*THIS IS COLOR B, THE OUTER ONE*/
#search span {
    background: #c4a76e;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 3%;
}

/*THIS IS COLOR A, THE INNER ONE*/
#search #txtSearch {
    float: left;
    border-radius: 3%;
    background: #fdf4d6;
    padding: 5%;
    border: thin solid black;
}
```

I plan to make the padding background color to color B, and the textfield it self color A, but its **not** working. I just get a textfield with background color A.

What should i do?

Any help is appreciated and just let me know if you need something else.

Thanks for your time :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, check DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/UcTsv/2/

## Screenshot

[image]

Use this css and done.

```
/*THIS IS COLOR B, THE OUTER ONE*/
#search span {
    float:left;
    margin:0;padding:0;
    border:2px solid #403726;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 7px; 
    border-radius: 7px;
    background:#d9b980;
}

/*THIS IS COLOR A, THE INNER ONE*/
#search #txtSearch {
    margin:0;
    width:170px;
    background: #ffe692;
    padding: 10px;
    border:5px solid #d9b980;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 8px; 
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much :D Could you please explain what you are doing?why are the both element need float:left?

Comment: Okie, we used float propertiy so that we can control the way information is presented in a more sophisticated way. more details here... http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 1):

hmmm... i'm seeing three colors.. black, brown and yellowish brown. but in case there's only brown and yellowish brown. you don't need `#search span` anymore.

you can just use 
`border: 3px solid #c4a76e;` for `#search #txtSearch`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i also think about this one :D

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking to code, and the colors might not be the same.. just picked them out randomly :)

http://codepen.io/AmruthPillai/pen/DJiao

Comment: Thanks very much for your help :D Its too bad i only can accept one answer

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify it even more, using just the input (example http://jsfiddle.net/slash197/2zn8B/):

CSS

```
input {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px #ff0000;
    background-color: #00ff00;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help :D Its too bad i only can accept one answer

Answer (score 1):

This comes a little close

```
<div id="search">
    <div><input type="text"  id="txtSearch"/></div>
</div>


#search div {
    border : solid 1px black;
    float : left;
    max-width : 100%;
    padding : 10px;
    background-color: #fdf4d6;
    border-radius: 3%;
}

#search #txtSearch {
    float : left;
    border-radius: 3%;
    background: #c4a76e;
    padding: 15px;
    border: solid 0px #fdf4d6;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help :D Its too bad i only can accept one answer